# Android Studio on El Capitan - issues in setting up the SDK

Tags: macos, android

Having issues while trying to set-up Android Studio (latest release, 2.3) on a Mac (El Capitan 10.11.3). Studio is installed, but when I launch it a window for configuring the SDK appears, and after a few passages I get this error:

"An error occurred while trying to compute required packages"

Anyone got this?

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

- Download the [command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads), place them in the SDK folder (e.g., on mac: `/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk`), unzip there and then add the tools/bin folder to the PATH.
- Install the latest platform: in a terminal, execute `sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"`
- Open Android Studio, and go to the SDK Manager (Appearance and Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK)
- Click on "Edit", and then select the sdk folder. Then "Next" > "Next" > "Finish".

I hope this works for you too.

Original answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732684/dependant-package-with-key-emulator-not-found-while-updating-android-sdk-and-too

P.S: I'm on Sierra, but I think that's not a macOS problem but Android Studio installer for mac.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Based on this and other advice, I have been able to step further. Please see here: https://superuser.com/questions/1187647/android-studio-on-mac-el-capitan-issues-in-setting-up-the-sdk/1187742#1187742